# How to test Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to test Firebase Dynamic Links.

The first scenario is easy. I can send proper intent using adb:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "https://myapp.app.goo.gl/shortlink"
```

I just wonder how can I test dynamic links with app installation process without Google Play Store. I just want to perform a similar test which is possible with branch.io:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.my.app/io.branch.referral.InstallListener --es "referrer" "link_click_id=4052874849443426113"
```

Is it possible with the Firebase Dynamic Links?

Comment: How did you solve it?